# Issue with UTF-8 encoding on Windows

Tags: java, swing, encoding, world-of-warcraft

I developed a little Java Swing application to look up character statistics in World of Warcraft with their developer API using Netbeans in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.  Everything works as I've intended with the exception of a button that calls a method that opens a link in the default browser to the specified character's profile.  On Ubuntu, the string I use in the URL renders correctly, but on Windows it does not.  If I run the application (in Windows) using a batch file that specifies UTF-8 encoding for the JVM, I do not have this issue.  When running it directly from the .jar file, characters such as "â" register as "Ã¢" in the URL on Windows despite my attempt at encoding all of my strings as UTF-8. How can I get the URL be properly formatted?  I'm assuming there's something I'm missing.  If you need to see more of the code, let me know.  Thank you in advance.

ArmoryScanner_UI.java

```
private void openArmoryLink() {

    ArmoryScanner_Backend armory = new ArmoryScanner_Backend();       
    String name;
    String realm;
    String locale;

    try {
        name = new String(jTextField_Name.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        realm = jComboBox_Realm.getSelectedItem().toString();
        locale = jComboBox_Locale.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (!name.trim().isEmpty()) {

            name = formatName(name);
            realm = formatRealm(realm);
            locale = formatLocale(locale);

            armory.setPlayerInfo(name, realm, locale);

            if (armory.isCharacterFound()) {
                armory.setArmoryLink();
            } else {
                showErrorMessage("Character not found.");
                jTextField_Name.setText("");
                jTextField_Name.setCaretPosition(0);
                jTextField_Name.requestFocus();
            }

        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Please enter a character name.");
            jTextField_Name.setText("");
            jTextField_Name.setCaretPosition(0);
            jTextField_Name.requestFocus();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        showErrorMessage("Error converting name to UTF-8\n"
                + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private String formatName(String name) {

    String result;
    try {
        result = new String(name.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        showErrorMessage("Error converting name to UTF-8\n"
                + e.getMessage());
        result = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

ArmoryScanner_Backend.java

```
public void setArmoryLink () {

    try {

        String baseURL = "https://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/";
        String fullURL = (baseURL + realm + "/" + name + "/simple");
        System.out.println("Full URL: " + fullURL);

        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(fullURL).toURI());
        } else {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                runtime.exec("xdg-open " + fullURL);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O exception (non-Windows system)");
            }
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        System.out.println("Unsupported OS");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Bad URL");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O exception.");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.out.println("Bad URI syntax");
    }

}
```

This method works fine:

```
private void submit() {

    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

    ArmoryScanner_Backend armory = new ArmoryScanner_Backend();       
    String name;
    String realm;
    String locale;

    try {

        name = new String(jTextField_Name.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));

        realm = jComboBox_Realm.getSelectedItem().toString();
        locale = jComboBox_Locale.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if (!name.trim().isEmpty()) {

            name = formatName(name);
            realm = formatRealm(realm);
            locale = formatLocale(locale);

            armory.setPlayerInfo(name, realm, locale);

            if (armory.isCharacterFound()) {

                setStatistics(armory);
                setProgression(armory);

            } else {
                showErrorMessage("Character not found.");
                jTextField_Name.setText("");
                jTextField_Name.setCaretPosition(0);
                jTextField_Name.requestFocus();
            }

        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Please enter a character name.");
            jTextField_Name.setText("");
            jTextField_Name.setCaretPosition(0);
            jTextField_Name.requestFocus();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        showErrorMessage("Error converting name to UTF-8\n"
                + e.getMessage());
    }

   this.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}
```

Comment: `Ã¢` _is_ UTF-8. The problem is that whatever is rendeting that into a glyph is not set to UTF-8 encoding and is trying to display it as if it were ASCII.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The `url` is the only part where you need to use explicit `UTF-8` encoding, and there you don't :) `URLEncoder.encode(stringToBeEncoded, "UTF-8")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java uses Unicode on the inside, so you don't usually need to set the encoding EXCEPT when you read/write outside resources.

There you need to have it explicitly.

In your case you need to encode the elements of the URL with the class URLEncoder.

Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

Comment: That couldn't have worked more perfectly. Thank you very much.